# Search for most north points or south points in a directed graph

Tags: graph-theory

I have a text file of 10000 connections int the following form:

> x1 y1 x2 y2

I would like to know if there exists an easy way to find all the north points and all the sounth points of a graph?

A point is south if connected to the x axis doesn't cross any other connection.

I thought about translating this problem to a line intersection problem, but I'am having difficulties implementing it.

Comment: By “connected to the x-axis”, do you mean that one of the endpoints lies on the x-axes? And when is a point “north”?

Comment: Yes, one endpoint lies on the x-axis and the x coordinate is the same as the x coordinate of the other endpoint(this represents a straight down line). A point is north when, connected to some other points (x,infinity) doesn't cross any other connection. Again, this represents a straight up line and the x coordinates of both enpoints are the same.